# Connecting Busbars Safely

Tags: electrical, safety, battery

I would like to design a 500-700V battery system such that I can laser weld a subset/module (i.e. a building block of ~12 cells each) with an open terminal on each end. This way, I can jump the positive open terminal of one module to the negative open terminal of another, combining all cells in series.

Ideally I would be able to laser weld all cells together, but with 150+ cells, that will not work given the available volume of the welder. Hence, the problem: I would like to **prevent an assembler from having to touch the busbars** when making the connection between cells.

One solution to this is to have busbar forks to essentially splice the busbars as shown here (where the 2 busbars at the top left would be mounted to the housing):
[image]

The white arrows indicate busbars that would be welded off of the empty terminals shown, where one terminal would be (+) and one would be (-). This would allow the assembler to push the cells back and into the busbar forks without needing to manually weld/bolt the connections down. The problem with this is that it takes up a lot of space in the direction of the cell rows, especially because I'd likely need to have the same setup on the other side of the cells.

Is there a lower profile (and less expensive if possible) option to do this? Is there a common way to connect battery modules together in series without touching the busbars/terminals during welding?

Thanks!